# OpenCV Mat::operator= - does it support copy on write?

Tags: c++, opencv

From the OpenCV documentation, it appears that copying a matrix is done using a shallow copy, but when changing one of the copies, a copy is done.

The exact [reference](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#cv-mat-operator) is:

> ```
> Mat& Mat::operator = (const Mat& m)
>
> Mat& Mat::operator = (const MatExpr_Base& expr)
>
> Mat& operator = (const Scalar& s)
> ```
>
> Matrix assignment operators
>
> Parameters:
>
> m – The assigned, right-hand-side
>   matrix. Matrix assignment is O(1)
>   operation, that is, no data is copied.
>   Instead, the data is shared and the
>   reference counter, if any, is
>   incremented. **Before assigning new
>   data, the old data is dereferenced via
>   Mat::release** .
>
> expr – The assigned matrix expression
>   object. As opposite to the first form
>   of assignment operation, the second
>   form can reuse already allocated
>   matrix if it has the right size and
>   type to fit the matrix expression
>   result. It is automatically handled by
>   the real function that the matrix
>   expressions is expanded to. For
>   example, C=A+B is expanded to
>   cv::add(A, B, C) , and add() will take
>   care of automatic C reallocation.
>
> s – The scalar, assigned to each
>   matrix element. The matrix size or
>   type is not changed.

However, this appears not to work

```
Mat_<float> a(5,5),b(5,5);
a =1;
b = a;
a = 2;
```

now b == 2, intead of 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you misunderstood. **"Before assigning new data, the old data is dereferenced via Mat::release"** does not mean that when you write on `a` or `b` then a copy occurs. It means that when you type `b=a`, you lose the data that was in b.

Long story short : copy on write is not supported.

Answer (score 5):

You can make a deep copy with `Mat::copyTo()`. E.g.

```
Mat a(5,5,CV_32C1),b;
a = 1;
a.copyTo(b);
a = 2;
```

But no, `Mat` does not support copy-on-write. When you need to make a change to `a` without affecting `b`, you need to make a deep copy of `a` to `b`, and then modify `a`.

Comment: You can also do Mat b = a.clone();