# Solve coplanar points pose estimation using EmguCV (OpenCV)

Tags: c#, math, opencv, computer-vision

I have 4 points on the same plane (a flat square object) detected in the camera and I am trying to work out the pose of this square relative to the camera.

I am using the latest version of EmguCV ( http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page ) which is a C# wrapper for OpenCV.

I have seen POSIT ( http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Posit ) but this will not work for coplanar points. I was wondering if there is anything that can solve coplanar pose estimation in OpenCV.

I have also seen solvePnp http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv-solvepnp
 which I believe will do what I want, but I cannot seem to find this functionality in EmguCV.

Does anyone know how to solve this using EmguCV?

Answer (score 0):

Although SolvePnP is not available in emgu, you can still compute a homography once you have at least 4 point correspondences on a plane (which you have). Refer to documentation for CameraCalibration.FindHomography in case you're unsure. Once you have the homography, you can decompose this into a rotation and translation, and hence the camera pose. Take a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927771/computing-camera-pose-with-homography-matrix-based-on-4-coplanar-points).

Answer (score 0):

Emgu.CV::CameraCalibration.SolvePnP(Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvPoint3D32f[], System.Drawing.PointF[], Emgu.CV.IntrinsicCameraParameters, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.SolvePnpMethod)

**Upgrade and install the latest NuGet package.**

Estimates extrinsic camera parameters using known intrinsic parameters and extrinsic parameters for each view. The coordinates of 3D object points and their correspondent 2D projections must be specified. This function also minimizes back-projection error.