# OpenCV SURF keypoints Comparison

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, surf, keypoint

I have 2 image with a little bit orientation to left in camera, i want to find the orientation from opencv, i get surf keypoints from 2 image and my problem is how to compare this 2 keypoints to find orientation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to apply a **matcher** (cv FlannMatcher for example) to detect which keypoints in both images correspond to the same point.

Then, with the paired matches you have to apply **cv::findHomography()**. This algorithm will use 4 matched pairs to extract the homography matrix.

The last step ([some code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10781165/744859)) is to convert from homography matrix to **pose matrix** (extrinsic parameters matrix). The pose matrix is composed by rotation and translation.

Comment: Though stackoverflow is not a place where you can ask for code I can link you to a explanation of how to get pose from homography:
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/2737/1473