# Finding the camera orientation from a homography, opencv

Tags: opencv, homography

If I have a camera which is already calibrated, so that I already know distortion coefficients, and the camera matrix. And that I have a set of points that all are in a plane, and I know the realworld metrics and pixel-location of those points, I have constructed a homography.

Given this homography, camera matrix and distortion coefficients, how can I find the camera pose in the easiest way? Prefferable by using openCV.

Can I for instance use the "DecomposeProjectionMatrix()" function?
It accepts only a 3x4 projection matrix, but I have a simple 3x3 homography

Comment: that is a much harder question that it seems.  Can you just use [solvePnP](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv-solvepnp) to get pose and ignore the homography you already have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10781165/744859) you have a method for that. It is a mathematical conversion that gives you the pose matrix, which is translation and rotation.