# Reprojection of pixels from one image into another

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, perspectivecamera, image-stitching, photogrammetry

I have a number of calibrated cameras taking a pictures of planar scene. For simplicity let's assume there are 3 cameras. Those cameras are undergoing general motion but mostly translation plus some mild rotation. [Example positions of cameras](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZDFo.png)

The task is to stitch them altogether. I have no knowledge about 3D coordinates, just a set of images taken with calibrated cameras.

What I do:

I detect features with SURF/SIFT implementations in OpenCV to get initial homographies by using **findHomography** between each pair of images (1->2, 2->3, 1->3). From those homographies I get initial esitimation of poses of each camera [(similiar procedure to this)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10781165/2080818)

Then I try to use bundle adjustment technique to minimize reprojection error for each matching pair. Optimized parameters are three translations values and three rotations values (obtained from Rodrigues' rotation formula) though I can add intrinsic parameters later (focals, principal points, etc).

Assuming image #2 will be reference frame (by having the most amount of matches to other two images) its rotation and translation matrices are identity and zero matrices respectively.

I calculate reprojection of keypoint (visible in both image #2 and image #1) from image #2 to image #1 as (pseudocode)

```
[x1_; y1_; z1_] = K1*R1*inv(K2)*[x2; y2; 1] + K1*T1/Z2;
x1 = x1_/z1_;
y1 = y1_/z1_;
```

or

```
x1 = ((f1/f2)*r11*x2 + (f1/f2)*r12*y2 + f1*r13 + f1*tx/Z2) / ((1/f2)*r31*x2 + (1/f2)*r32*y2 + r33 + tx/Z2)
y1 = ((f1/f2)*r21*x2 + (f1/f2)*r22*y2 + f1*r23 + f1*ty/Z2) / ((1/f2)*r31*x2 + (1/f2)*r32*y2 + r33 + ty/Z2)
```

where r__ are elements of R1 matrix and both intrinsic matrices are in the form of

```
[f 0 0]
[0 f 0]
[0 0 1]
```

I'm assuming Z2 coordinate of reference frame as 1.

Next stage is to warp images #1 and #3 into common coordinate system of image #2 using obtained camera matrices (K1,R1,T1,K3,R3,T3).

The issue is that I have no knowledge about Z1 and Z3 needed for correct reprojection into reference frame of image #2 because invert reprojection from image #1->#2 looks like this:

```
x2 = ((f2/f1)*R11*x1 + (f2/f1)*R12*y1 + f2*R13 - f0/Z1*(R11*tx + R12*ty + R13*tz)) / ((1/f1)*R31*x1 + (1/f1)*R32*y1 + R33 - 1/Z1*(R31*tx + R32*ty + R33*tz))
y2 = ((f2/f1)*R21*x1 + (f2/f1)*R22*y1 + f2*R23 - f0/Z1*(R21*tx + R22*ty + R23*tz)) / ((1/f1)*R31*x1 + (1/f1)*R32*y1 + R33 - 1/Z1*(R31*tx + R32*ty + R33*tz))
```

where R__ are elements of inv(R1) matrix.

Is there a better way of calculating reprojection error for bundle adjustment (2d->2d) and then warping images into common coordinates system? I noticed that OpenCV has very similiar framework in their stitching module but it operates under assumption of pure rotation motion which is not the case here.

Comment: Did you thought about 3D triangulation ? You could for example triangulate a point with all but one cameras and reproject it in the last one.

Answer (score 1):

I autoanswered that question in my post [How to get points in stereo image from extrinsic parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475190/how-to-get-points-in-stereo-image-from-extrinsic-parameters/15495933#15495933)

Note that the method I use (Tested and working!) it is only valid if the object in 3D coordinates (real world!) is planar and it is at Z=0 (the point where you calibrated the extrinsic parameters of the cameras). In that case this method is as precise as your calibration is. Note: for the best calibration check openCVs circle calibrations, it has a reproyection error of 0.018 pixels (tested by a PhD student working in my university).

Answer (score 1):

You probably have discovered a bug on the repojection error. It has to do with this line:

```
[x1_; y1_; z1_] = K1*R1*inv(K2)*[x2; y2; 1] + K1*T1/Z2;
```

The point [x2; y2; 1] is ambiguous up to a scale constant, C*[x2; y2; 1] and here you are setting C=1 when it is generally unknown. The locus of possibilities manifests itself as an *epipolar line* in the first view. You can use least-squares triangulation to find the most likely point along this line that the 3D point exists, and then compute the re-projected point as:

```
[x1_; y1_; z1_] = K1*(R1*X + T1);
```

and proceed from there as you have above. The 3D coordinates of each such point X in your point cloud can be computed using its corresponding normalized coordinates (x1,y1), (x2,y2),..., as well as the corresponding rotation matrices and translation vectors, by formatting them into the matrix problem:

```
A X = b
```

and then solving least-squares:

```
min |A X - b|_2
```

which is illustrated on pages 3 and 4 [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?rep=rep1&type=pdf&doi=10.1.1.124.5096).