# Pose estimation with emgu

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, emgucv, photogrammetry

I would like to do pose estimation of a chessboard target using emgu. I have already determined the camera intrinsics. However, I can't find the solvePnP function in emgu which I think should solve my problem.

Does anybody know how I could find this function in emgu?

Is there another way to do pose estimation using emgu? I suppose I could use the CalibrateCamera camera and use the extrinsics in some way... but I think this more computational heavy than needed. Or is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find chessboard corners using emgu, refer to CameraCalibration.FindChessboardCorners. Once you have the corners, you will be able to draw point correspondences between an ideal chessboard and your image.

Although SolvePnP is not available in emgu, you can still compute a homography once you have at least 4 point correspondences on a plane (which you now have). Refer to CameraCalibration.FindHomography. Once you have the homography, you can decompose this into a rotation and translation, and hence the camera pose. Take a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927771/computing-camera-pose-with-homography-matrix-based-on-4-coplanar-points).