# Camera pose estimation from homography or with solvePnP() function

Tags: ios, opencv, augmented-reality, scenekit, homography

I'm trying to build static augmented reality scene over a photo with 4 defined correspondences between coplanar points on a plane and image.

**Here is a step by step flow:**

1. User adds an image using device's camera. Let's assume it contains a rectangle captured with some perspective.
2. User defines physical size of the rectangle, which lies in horizontal plane (YOZ in terms of SceneKit). Let's assume it's center is world's origin (0, 0, 0), so we can easily find (x,y,z) for each corner.
3. User defines uv coordinates in image coordinate system for each corner of the rectangle.
4. SceneKit scene is created with a rectangle of the same size, and visible at the same perspective.
5. Other nodes can be added and moved in the scene.

[image: Flow]

I've also measured position of the iphone camera relatively to the center of the A4 paper. So for this shot the position was (0, 14, 42.5) measured in cm. Also my iPhone was slightly pitched to the table (5-10 degrees)

Using this data I've set up `SCNCamera` to get the desired perspective of the blue plane on the third image:

```
let camera = SCNCamera()
camera.xFov = 66
camera.zFar = 1000
camera.zNear = 0.01

cameraNode.camera = camera
cameraAngle = -7 * CGFloat.pi / 180
cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: Float(cameraAngle))
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 14, z: 42.5)
```

This will give me a reference to compare my result with.

**In order to build AR with SceneKit I need to:**

1. Adjust SCNCamera's fov, so that it matches real camera's fov.
2. Calculate position and rotation for camera node using 4 correnspondensies between world points (x,0,z) and image points (u, v)

[image: Equation]

**H** - homography; **K** - Intrinsic matrix; **[R | t]** - Extrinsic matrix

I tried two approaches in order to find transform matrix for camera: using solvePnP from OpenCV and manual calculation from homography based on 4 coplanar points.

### Manual approach:

**1. Find out homography**

[image: Homography]

This step is done successfully, since UV coordinates of world's origin seems to be correct.

**2. Intrinsic matrix**

In order to get intrinsic matrix of iPhone 6, I have used [this](https://itunes.apple.com/kz/app/vizario.cam/id1067654472) app, which gave me the following result out of 100 images of 640*480 resolution:

[image: Intrinsic]

Assuming that input image has 4:3 aspect ratio, I can scale the above matrix depending on resolution

[image: Intrinsic2]

I am not sure but it feels like a potential problem here. I've used cv::calibrationMatrixValues to check fovx for the calculated intrinsic matrix and the result was ~50°, while it should be close to 60°.

**3. Camera pose matrix**

```
func findCameraPose(homography h: matrix_float3x3, size: CGSize) -> matrix_float4x3? {
    guard let intrinsic = intrinsicMatrix(imageSize: size),
        let intrinsicInverse = intrinsic.inverse else { return nil }

    let l1 = 1.0 / (intrinsicInverse * h.columns.0).norm
    let l2 = 1.0 / (intrinsicInverse * h.columns.1).norm
    let l3 = (l1+l2)/2

    let r1 = l1 * (intrinsicInverse * h.columns.0)
    let r2 = l2 * (intrinsicInverse * h.columns.1)
    let r3 = cross(r1, r2)

    let t = l3 * (intrinsicInverse * h.columns.2)

    return matrix_float4x3(columns: (r1, r2, r3, t))
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Since I measured the approximate position and orientation for this particular image, I know the transform matrix, which would give the expected result and it is quite different:

[image: Target result]

I am also a bit conserned about 2-3 element of reference rotation matrix, which is -9.1, while it should be close to zero instead, since there is very slight rotation.

### OpenCV approach:

There is a [solvePnP](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#bool%20solvePnP(InputArray%20objectPoints,%20InputArray%20imagePoints,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs,%20OutputArray%20rvec,%20OutputArray%20tvec,%20bool%20useExtrinsicGuess,%20int%20flags)) function in OpenCV for this kind of problems, so I tried to use it instead of reinventing the wheel.

OpenCV in Objective-C++:

```
typedef struct CameraPose {
    SCNVector4 rotationVector;
    SCNVector3 translationVector; 
} CameraPose;

+ (CameraPose)findCameraPose: (NSArray<NSValue *> *) objectPoints imagePoints: (NSArray<NSValue *> *) imagePoints size: (CGSize) size {

    vector<Point3f> cvObjectPoints = [self convertObjectPoints:objectPoints];
    vector<Point2f> cvImagePoints = [self convertImagePoints:imagePoints withSize: size];

    cv::Mat distCoeffs(4,1,cv::DataType<double>::type, 0.0);
    cv::Mat rvec(3,1,cv::DataType<double>::type);
    cv::Mat tvec(3,1,cv::DataType<double>::type);
    cv::Mat cameraMatrix = [self intrinsicMatrixWithImageSize: size];

    cv::solvePnP(cvObjectPoints, cvImagePoints, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec);

    SCNVector4 rotationVector = SCNVector4Make(rvec.at<double>(0), rvec.at<double>(1), rvec.at<double>(2), norm(rvec));
    SCNVector3 translationVector = SCNVector3Make(tvec.at<double>(0), tvec.at<double>(1), tvec.at<double>(2));
    CameraPose result = CameraPose{rotationVector, translationVector};

    return result;
}

+ (vector<Point2f>) convertImagePoints: (NSArray<NSValue *> *) array withSize: (CGSize) size {
    vector<Point2f> points;
    for (NSValue * value in array) {
        CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
        points.push_back(Point2f(point.x - size.width/2, point.y - size.height/2));
    }
    return points;
}

+ (vector<Point3f>) convertObjectPoints: (NSArray<NSValue *> *) array {
    vector<Point3f> points;
    for (NSValue * value in array) {
        CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
        points.push_back(Point3f(point.x, 0.0, -point.y));
    }
    return points;
}

+ (cv::Mat) intrinsicMatrixWithImageSize: (CGSize) imageSize {
    double f = 0.84 * max(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    Mat result(3,3,cv::DataType<double>::type);
    cv::setIdentity(result);
    result.at<double>(0) = f;
    result.at<double>(4) = f;
    return result;
}
```

Usage in Swift:

```
func testSolvePnP() {
    let source = modelPoints().map { NSValue(cgPoint: $0) }
    let destination = perspectivePicker.currentPerspective.map { NSValue(cgPoint: $0)}

    let cameraPose = CameraPoseDetector.findCameraPose(source, imagePoints: destination, size: backgroundImageView.size);    
    cameraNode.rotation = cameraPose.rotationVector
    cameraNode.position = cameraPose.translationVector
}
```

**Output:**

[image: OpenCV result]
[image: SolvePnP result]

The result is better but far from my expectations.

**Some other things I've also tried:**

1. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927771/computing-camera-pose-with-homography-matrix-based-on-4-coplanar-points) is very similar, though I don't understand how the accepted answer is working without intrinsics.
2. [decomposeHomographyMat](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#decomposehomographymat) also didn't give me the result I expected

**I am really stuck with this issue so any help would be much appreciated.**

Comment: Read quickly the question. For 1), for me the intrinsic is needed. I think it didn't appear in the equations because they expressed image points in the normalized camera frame (more information [here](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01246370/file/survey-ieee-v2.pdf)). From [u,v] coordinate and intrinsics, you can compute point in the normalized camera frame. If you have somehow (by the user) the pairs of points: 2D image points and 3D object points, the easiest solution is to use `solvePnP()`.

Comment: To debug, I suggest you to validate: 1) the intrinsic parameters, 2) each pair of points (2D / 3D) must match (correspond to the same physical corner), 3) try with the same image resolution than the one use for the calibration. In order, I would go first with 3), 2) and 1). Otherwise, both solutions (homography estimation and `solvePnP()`) should work. Pose from homography will work only for planar object and is more complicated. `solvePnP()` will give directly the rotation and translation vector for the camera pose.

Comment: Has the AR stuff in iOS 11 solved/helped with any of this **AMAZINGLY WELL ARTICULATED** question?

Comment: @Catree My mistake was in converting back to SpriteKit coordinates system, as described below. Anyway, thank you for your suggestions ;)

Comment: @Confused Yes, I think ARKit would simplify my problem a lot. But I needed a solution for iOS 9-10. Moreover ARKit is supported only by new devices starting from 6s/6s plus :(

Comment: @alexburtnik The devil is in the detail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually I was one step away from the working solution with **OpenCV**.

My problem with second approach was that I forgot to convert the output from `solvePnP` back to SpriteKit's coordinate system. 
[image]

Note that the input (image and world points) was actually converted correctly to OpenCV coordinate system (`convertObjectPoints:` and `convertImagePoints:withSize:` methods)

So here is a fixed `findCameraPose` method with some comments and intermediate results printed:

```
+ (CameraPose)findCameraPose: (NSArray<NSValue *> *) objectPoints imagePoints: (NSArray<NSValue *> *) imagePoints size: (CGSize) size {

    vector<Point3f> cvObjectPoints = [self convertObjectPoints:objectPoints];
    vector<Point2f> cvImagePoints = [self convertImagePoints:imagePoints withSize: size];

    std::cout << "object points: " << cvObjectPoints << std::endl;
    std::cout << "image points: " << cvImagePoints << std::endl;

    cv::Mat distCoeffs(4,1,cv::DataType<double>::type, 0.0);
    cv::Mat rvec(3,1,cv::DataType<double>::type);
    cv::Mat tvec(3,1,cv::DataType<double>::type);
    cv::Mat cameraMatrix = [self intrinsicMatrixWithImageSize: size];

    cv::solvePnP(cvObjectPoints, cvImagePoints, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec);

    std::cout << "rvec: " << rvec << std::endl;
    std::cout << "tvec: " << tvec << std::endl;

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> projectedPoints;
    cvObjectPoints.push_back(Point3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    cv::projectPoints(cvObjectPoints, rvec, tvec, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, projectedPoints);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < projectedPoints.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "Image point: " << cvImagePoints[i] << " Projected to " << projectedPoints[i] << std::endl;
    }


    cv::Mat RotX(3, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type);
    cv::setIdentity(RotX);
    RotX.at<double>(4) = -1; //cos(180) = -1
    RotX.at<double>(8) = -1;

    cv::Mat R;
    cv::Rodrigues(rvec, R);

    R = R.t();  // rotation of inverse
    Mat rvecConverted;
    Rodrigues(R, rvecConverted); //
    std::cout << "rvec in world coords:\n" << rvecConverted << std::endl;
    rvecConverted = RotX * rvecConverted;
    std::cout << "rvec scenekit :\n" << rvecConverted << std::endl;

    Mat tvecConverted = -R * tvec;
    std::cout << "tvec in world coords:\n" << tvecConverted << std::endl;
    tvecConverted = RotX * tvecConverted;
    std::cout << "tvec scenekit :\n" << tvecConverted << std::endl;

    SCNVector4 rotationVector = SCNVector4Make(rvecConverted.at<double>(0), rvecConverted.at<double>(1), rvecConverted.at<double>(2), norm(rvecConverted));
    SCNVector3 translationVector = SCNVector3Make(tvecConverted.at<double>(0), tvecConverted.at<double>(1), tvecConverted.at<double>(2));

    return CameraPose{rotationVector, translationVector};
}
```

Notes:

1. `RotX` matrix means [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) by 180 degrees around x axis, which will transform any vector from OpenCV coordinate system to SpriteKit's
2. [Rodrigues](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#void%20Rodrigues(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20OutputArray%20jacobian)) method transforms rotation vector to rotation matrix (3x3) and vice versa

Comment: How can I get the objectPoints and imagePoints after calculating Homography ?