# OpenCV - assign operator "not working"?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have one function to compute convolution (to test whether we are using correct settings for `filter2D`), I think the function body is not important, so here's just header and the end:

```cpp
template<typename T>
cv::Mat conv(const cv::Mat &input, const cv::Mat &kernel) {
    cv::Mat output(input); // or should I rather use output( input.rows, input.cols, input.depth())?

    ...
    return output;
}

cv::Mat result = conv( input, kernel);
```

At this point, I have completely useless results in `result` (those aren't even random data, they have some strange pattern which got repeated every time I run the function).

When I rewrite function to:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void conv(const cv::Mat &input, cv::Mat &output, const cv::Mat &kernel) {
   ...
}

cv::Mat result(input);
conv( input, result, kernel);
```

Everything works just fine and result matrix contains exactly what it should.

So my **question** is: What's wrong on first approach? Am I doing something wrong? Why isn't assign operator/return from function working?

*Note: OpenCv version: extra/opencv 2.3.1_a-3 (archlinux package)*

*Something similar happened to me when I was loading external data from opencv storage and data got lost until I used `data( loaded.clone())`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that `filter2d`, or whatever you do, does not work 'in-place', that is, when input and output are the same. With your first line in the function,

```
cv::Mat output(input); // or should I rather use output( input.rows, input.cols, input.depth())?
```

you make output point to the same data as input! It is *not* a clone, it is another reference!

What you want to do is written in your comment. Another option may be (depending on your code) to let output completely uninitialized, as typically C++ OpenCV functions will initialize their output matrices for you, if they are empty.

Note that your `conv()`, even when giving a proper `results`, would always destroy your `input` matrix on the way. **OpenCV does not respect const** in its internal data reference meachanism. Yes, it is bad design.

Comment: If I understand correctly than the second you change the data (and I change them a lot, every cell) all data are copied to new "smart pointer item". If you take a look at the second approach, you will notice that I'm using `result(input)` and it works just fine than.

Comment: No, there is no copy-on-write in OpenCV, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411476/opencv-matoperator-does-it-support-copy-on-write I don't know what your function in the second approach does, maybe it overwrites result in a way that it is re-initialized. Then input is left untouched.

Comment: Yes I've read that question and answers and it make me believe that bot my approaches should work. Not just the second one. Body of function is in both codes same (it applies (Gabor) filter).

Comment: I'll be damned: http://pastebin.com/0NMQy7wU, http://pastebin.com/WgNAB6fm , thanks.