# Get frame video with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, video-processing

This is my code to get frame from video. I want to show 2 frame in video with looping and condition.

```
    int main( int argc, char** argv )
    {    

    string fileName = "E:\\Tugas Akhir\\Video Master\\city_1.avi";
    Mat image1;
    Mat image2;
    Mat frame;
    cv::Mat result;
    VideoCapture cap(fileName); 
    if(!cap.isOpened())  
        return -1;

    Mat edges;
    for(int loop=0;;loop++)
    {
        //std::cout<<loop<<endl;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        if(loop>0 && (loop%20)==0){             
            //std::cout<<"frame 2"<<endl;
            image2=frame;                               
            **imshow("image2",image2);**
            break;      
        }else if(loop==0){          
            image1=frame;
            **imshow("image1",image1);**
            //std::cout<<"frame 1"<<endl;

        }
        //loop++;


        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }


 waitKey(0);
 return 0;
 }
```

And here's the result, 2 windows with 2 different image

[image]

but when i change imshow("image1",image1) method position ...

```
           if(loop>0 && (loop%20)==0){              
            //std::cout<<"frame 2"<<endl;
            image2=frame;

            **imshow("image1",image1);**
            **imshow("image2",image2);**
            break;      
        }else if(loop==0){          
            image1=frame;

            //std::cout<<"frame 1"<<endl;

        }
```

image1 windows show same picture with image2, 
[image]

i don't know why it show strange result, please tell me how to fix it, thank you

Comment: It is not clear what your are going to do.

Answer (score 3):

an assignment like this:

```
image1 = frame;
```

does only a *shallow* copy. the Mat struct gets copied, the pixels are *shared*

so, in your 2nd example  you're overwriting image1 with the current frame. if you want to 'cache' Mats, use:

```
image1 = frame.clone(); // deep copy
```

Comment: Also, you can use Mat::copyTo() method for deep-copying a Mat. Another way is using any operation on the original Mat (e.g. A = 1.0*B; or A = B+0.0; will copy the data in B to A).

Answer (score 1):

What you're facing is essentially the lack of support for [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) in OpenCV Mat's overloaded `=` operator. It basically means that `image1` and `frame` will share their data.

A convenient way of seeing this is, when you write `image1 = frame`, called "shallow copying", you're creating a reference `image1` to the Mat `frame`. So after 20 iterations when you display `image1`, you're actually displaying `frame` itself.

This wouldn't be the case if you'd written something like `image1 = frame.clone()`, because in that case you're actually making a separate copy of `frame`.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411476/opencv-matoperator-does-it-support-copy-on-write) out.